# sumar datos de la semana en curso

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de productos:

```
id  | descripcion

1      latas
```

y una tabla de servicios:

```
id |  id_producto |  cantidad |       fecha

1       1              2        2022-04-27 11:41:17.327
2       1              5        2022-04-26 11:45:23.327
3       1              1        2022-04-27 11:48:17.327
4       1              2        2022-04-18 11:41:17.327
```

Necesito calcular la cantidad vendida de la semana en curso, es decir, mi semana inicio el lunes `25` y mi cierre de semana es el siguiente lunes.

Como se puede ver solamente una venta el `18`, pero esa es de la semana pasada, solamente necesitaria sumar las ventas de la semana en curso hasta que termine la misma.

Tengo este query, no esta completo, pero es que no se mas va o como hacerlo:

```
SELECT sum(cantidad) FROM servicios where id_producto = '1' and datepart >= 1 then datepart <= 1
```

Lo que e intentado es sumar las cantidades que van de este lunes al siguiente de un producto en especifico, desde el dia `25` al dia `2` de mayo, me tendria que dar como resultado 8, puesto que solo hay una cantidad del dia de ayer y `2` del dia de hoy, y si se hicieran mas mañana eso tambien debera de sumarse al total.

Para el cierre e inicio de la siguiente semana ya tendra que ser diferente depende las cantidades de esa semana en curso

Comment: ¿De qué base de datos se trataría?

Comment: es de sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el principal problema en tu caso es como determinar la "semana en curso", ciertamente la fecha actual la obtienes con un `GETDATE()` ahora, para saber desde hoy, cual es la fecha del lunes y cual es la del domingo hay que hacer unos cálculos, teniendo en cuenta el `@@DATEFIRST` con el que esta configurado el motor. Voy a copiar [esta lógica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267458/6836377) que funciona muy bien y es agnóstica de la configuración del servidor:

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATE

SET @Hoy = GETDATE()

SELECT  @Hoy                                                                Hoy,
        DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)   Lunes,
        DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)   Domingo
```

Ahora es trivial implementarlo en tu consulta:

```
SELECT sum(cantidad) 
       FROM servicios 
       where id_producto = '1' 
             and fecha >= DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy) 
             and fecha <= DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)
```